# lapply on dataframe with names()

Tags: r, lapply

Why doesn't `lapply` return a list of names as elements? What's the technical reason for it?

```
   > library(ISLR)
    lapply(Auto, names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the `names` of 'data.frame' in a `list`

```
as.list(names(Auto))
```

---

When we loop the  data.frame columns with `lapply`, it will be a `list` of `vector`s.

```
head(lapply(Auto, head,3),2)
#$mpg
#[1] 18 15 18

#$cylinders
#[1] 8 8 8
```

As we notice above, it is a `vector` and the `column names` are now the `list` names.  So, doing

```
lapply(Auto, names)
```

results in `NULL` for each `list` element.

Comment: I understand that, but what's the reason for strange output of `lapply`?

Comment: @guyguyguy12345  When you are looping over `lapply`, the elements are vector and not data.frame, so it doesn't have any names.